# Is it possible to share sensitive data to a js script in the browser?

Tags: javascript, security

So what I mean is. Say you're building a web app which needs to make use of an external service. And that external service requires you to authenticate with them using a `client_id` and a `client_secret`. So I would like the javascript to be able to find out what the `client_id` and the `client_secret` is without any random developer who can open developer tools being able to find them out.

Is that even possible? Is it possible to encrypt such things or at least obscure it so much that it's very impractical for an average developer to find out how to get those keys?

A few things I've read about sometimes is that you can put data / code in a png and then read that png as code in javascript. That seems like an acceptable method, since I think most people wouldn't think about looking at the loaded images, right? And I'm guessing I would somehow need to uglify the javascript itself as much as possible too right? Are there any more methods like that?

Comment: No, it's not possible. You should make the API call from your server, not the client.

Comment: Even if you obscure the Javascript, they can just go to the Network tab of DevTools to see what gets sent to the external service.

Comment: Use your server as a proxy.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to encrypt such things or at least obscure it so much that it's very impractical for an average developer to find out how to get those keys?

No.

> That seems like an acceptable method, since I think most people wouldn't think about looking at the loaded images, right?

Then the user just needs to look at the Network tab in their browser and watch the HTTP request to the webservice and extract the secret from there. There's no need for them to decode your source code.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking at obfuscation and minification. This fits your description. However it is not possible to truly hide something in Javascript, no matter how distorted you make it, it can always be retrieved by another developer / hacker

Comment: values will still be clear as day in the network request.

Comment: That's what i said.. it can always be retrieved?